older version of firefox in fresh ubuntu studio 24.04.1 installation
I am posting this question in case others encounter this problem.  After a fresh installation of Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS in which I continued to use the /home from my previous (Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS) installation, Firefox greeted me with the message, "Using an older version of Firefox can corrupt...", evidently because the Firefox profile in my /home was from a newer version of Firefox.
Even after installing all available updates in Discover, Firefox remained at v129, although the current version is 132.0.

I looked up Firefox in Discover under "Installed" and clicked on the button, "Channels" at the bottom of the right hand pane. It showed a list of 6 channels, with none selected.  I clicked on the last entry (latest/stable) and clicked the button "Switch" at the right. Discover didn't find anything new that way, so I opened a console window and executed:
sudo snap refresh firefox

which then updated Firefox to v132.0. I was then able to start Firefox using my old profile without incident.
